# Is it possible to make a linked html pop out in a new window and not a new tab despite the browser settings

Tags: javascript, firefox, router

I have mozzilla firefox (technically Aurora 15) browser and I have the browser set so all new windows open in a new tab. Till recently I though it was impossible to make the link pop up in a new window with any sort of javascript or anything similar like that.
But i was surprised that my router's 'site' has managed to do that. (the thing you access with 192.168.0.1)

I have a Netgear modem router (DG834G).

When i go to `Basic Settings` at the bottom of the page I have `Test` button and when i click it a new window pops up which refreshes every couple of seconds telling you about connection status etc and if connection is successful it directs you to the netgear website.

What i dont understand is how the website pops up in a new window. From what i see the router is using javascript to do this. 
Is it possible to accomplish this with javascript or do routers receive special treatment??

Comment: No; this is up to your users to enforce via their browser settings.

Comment: It is a router and it is a web server. You know they are in the same box, but your browser does not. It is possible to figure out that they share an ip/mac address. But there will be nowhere in the OS or browser that does this. They are independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is. Just add width and height and the browser (not all) will open it in a new windows instead of tab.

```
window.open(url, windowName, "height=200,width=200");
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally `window.open();` opens a new window.

More info about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open

If this doesn't work you, could you please post the javascript used in the page, so we can take a look at it?

Comment: The Mozilla page talks about the "window object". This covers both tabs and separate windows.